# Can you performance test Siebel applications using JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, siebel

Is it possible to record JMeter scripts for performance testing Siebel?

Comment: Did you find answer to your question ? Please gve feedback ...

Comment: No I didn't, but looks like the guys at work will be using Load Runner (which you have to pay for)/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Siebel uses a custom format for ENCODING its requests plus some necessary technical parameters.

So it's possible provided it's the http module  but rather hard job as there are a lot of correlations to do on technical IDs.

For recording, see this:

- [JMeter record Siebel CRM System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48948992/jmeter-record-siebel-crm-system/49135608#49135608)

You can use this commercial plugin that will do auto-correlation for you:

- https://ubikloadpack.com/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to test Siebel with JMeter. I have done so for one of my projects with my client TataSky where I have used JMeters distributed testing approach for generating upto 2000 users with 4 - 5 normal desktops. Siebel uses http protocol so it is finally about understanding the requests sent by browser and responses by the web-server and correlating between them. It gets really messy though, so my suggestion is correlate **parameters which are mandatory.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JMeter-Siebel-plugin](https://github.com/Blazemeter/SiebelPlugin/blob/master/README.md) which provides **Siebel HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder** test element handy for capturing and correlating Siebel traffic.

The plugin can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

[image]

Check out Introducing the [Siebel CRM Correlation Plugin in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-the-siebel-crm-correlation-plugin-on-jmeter) article for comprehensive instructions.

Comment: Siebel CRM Correlation Plugin in JMeter is compatible with which Siebel versions?