# JMeter record Siebel CRM System

Tags: jmeter, recorder

I am trying to record a Siebel CRM System using JMeter HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder but I get the below exception:

```
java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.http.client.entity.DeflateInputStream.read(DeflateInputStream.java:88)
at org.apache.http.client.entity.LazyDecompressingInputStream.read(LazyDecompressingInputStream.java:70)
at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:135)
at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:148)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.readResponse(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1814)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPAbstractImpl.readResponse(HTTPAbstractImpl.java:440)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:474)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1189)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:244)
```

I am using JMeter 3.3. Any thoughts on how to workaround this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to a kind of buggy stream served by Siebel as per:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1869
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1877

Still this has been workaround in JMeter > 4.0:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61058

You can try nightly build (after 6 march 2018) of jmeter or wait for 4.1:

- https://builds.apache.org/job/JMeter-trunk/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/trunk/dist/

And set in user.properties then restart JMeter:

> httpclient4.deflate_relax_mode=true